# How can I insert result of JS function in html form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question - how insert result of JS function in html form?
I need to put time (in hh:mm format) into "value" in form.
The JS code:

```
function getHours() {
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
document.getElementById('clientid').value=h+" "+m;}
```

The HTML form:

```
<html>
<form method='post' action='http.example.com/some.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='clientid' id='clientid' value="test" action="javascript:getHours()" />
</form>
</html>
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You don't need to wrap your code within a function...

Comment: When do you want the value to be set in the clientid field?

Comment: what are you trying to do you want to set `value` to `<input type='hidden' name='clientid' id='clientid' value="test" action="javascript:getHours()" />` which is `hidden`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load your function like this:

```
<html>

<body onload="getHours()">
    <form method='post' action='http.example.com/some.php'>
        <input type='hidden' name='clientid' id='clientid' value="test" action="javascript:getHours()" />
    </form>

<script>
    function getHours() {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = d.getHours();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        document.getElementById('clientid').value = h + " " + m;
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = h + ':' + m ;
$('#clientid').val($time);
```

the `$time = h + ':' + m ;` adds the hours and minute to the format you want to the `$time` variable.

After that the `$('#clientid').val($time);` tells JS to add that variable to the **clientid** 's value.

Comment: do you see `jquery` tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`onload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) method to call your function `getHours()`, but `.onload()` support following `tags`:
`<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 var name = "Beginner";
 document.getElementById("clientid").setAttribute("value", name);
});
</script>

<input name='clientid' id='clientid' />
```